# Stubbing/Mocking-Out the Persistence Layer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In other languages and technology stacks, I was always told to mock/stub the database layer and all external services when writing unit tests. However, the RoR crowd tends to not mock/stub the database layer and sometimes even makes Active Record calls (.e.g. #find) in the controller (shudder).

On the one hand, Active Record is super awesome and makes so many tasks super easy. It makes the representation of object graphs very easy and nice. On the other hand, I can't seem to shake the feeling that calling #find on Active Record in the controller is bad design. If I were to place an abstraction layer in-between my application and Active Record thereby only returning data-transfer objects from the persistence layer, then I will have to write a more code. However, my tests would be super fast and the architectural design of the application would be closer to the design I am used to.

What are everyone's thoughts on the subject?

Comment: If you seriously have a problem with User.find calls in your controller you might want to use another framework.

Comment: If we accept User.find in the controller is fine, then is Client.select(:name).distinct.limit(5).offset(30)? If we allow that, then is it also acceptable to add an "unless" clause? I am trying to figure out where the limit it. When do I know when I have too much in the controller? Doing this also implies that I will always be querying a database in my tests. Is this amount of database churn OK?